# Show Subcategory Description

Tags: categories, description

I'm using the following code to show the subcategories of a category within my archive.php page:

```
<?php if (is_category()) {
  $this_category = get_category($cat);
  if (get_category_children($this_category->cat_ID) != "") {
    echo "<div id='catlist'><ul>";
    wp_list_categories('orderby=name&hide_empty=0&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID);
    echo "</ul></div>";
  }
}?>
```

The code above returns the name of the category as a link, with the category description as the link title.

Can anyone show my how to show the category description within paragraph tags after the category link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_list_categories` formats the results, instead you want to try `get_categories` and create your own loop to format the results.

I do not know exactly how you want it formated, but this gives you the general idea.

```
<?php 
if (is_category()) {
    $this_category = get_category($cat);
    if (get_category_children($this_category->cat_ID) != "") {
        echo '<div id="catlist"><ul>';
        $childcategories = get_categories(array(
            'orderyby' => 'name',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'child_of' => $this_category->cat_ID
            ));
        foreach($childcategories as $category) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>';
            echo '<p>'.$category->description.'</p>';
        }
        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

For more examples and information visit, [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)